# Copy multipal file based on file names

Tags: python, python-2.7

Based on the first 3 characters of a file name i want to create a folder then copy in the related file.

I have a script that works the first time, however i get an error if I run it multiple times 
I believe i need to check if the file exists first, however i haven't been able to get it work. 
Or to filter out the newly created folders from the os.list

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
srcpath = 'C:\\temp\\Test'
srcfiles = os.listdir(srcpath)
destpath = 'C:\\temp\\Test'

# extract the three letters from filenames
destdirs = list(set([filename[0:3] for filename in srcfiles]))


def create(destdirs, destpath):
    full_path = os.path.join(destpath, destdirs)
    if not os.path.exists(full_path):
        os.mkdir(full_path)
    return full_path


def copy(filename, dirpath):
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(srcpath, filename), dirpath)

# create destination directories and store their names along with full paths
targets = [
    (folder, create(folder, destpath)) for folder in destdirs
]

for destdirs, full_path in targets:
     for filename in srcfiles:
          if destdirs == filename[0:3]:
              copy(filename, full_path)
```

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/copy_only.py", line 45, in <module>
    copy(filename, full_path)
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/copy_only.py", line 35, in copy
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(srcpath, filename), dirpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 119, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\temp\\Test\\F12'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to open a directory `C:\\temp\\Test\\F12` as the `filename` in `copy`.
Otherwise, please check if you have the permission to open/read the file.

Comment: correct it is trying to open F12 as a filename. Thats why i want to filter out folders in the listdir.The director is on a local computer will full rights, so i don't believe it's a permission issue